# UV4L MJPEG Streaming

Tags: raspicam, streaming-video, uv4l

May I know how to determine the number of streaming connections to uv4l from Python when the streaming server is running in Raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an INFO page accessible from the homepage of the UV4L Streaming Server which reports the information you need.

Comment: Thanks strumpet. I was also looking in to that and to extract number of connections from it's output.

Comment: One more thing, not sure I would have to open up a new thread, but even though I set a user password in uv4l it never prompted me to key in when accessed the live mjpeg stream. It simply show the stream. Kindly advise.

Comment: authentication works fine. just tested.